# Como según dato de mi DB pongo una imagen con foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

Hola me explico mejor jeje, tengo una tabla que tiene un campo llamado status y quiero que me cuando me lea ese status ( 1 y 0) me ponga una imagen en mi tabla, tengo algo asi:

```
    <?php
  require "../php/conector.php";
  // require_once "../metodosCrud/metodoscrud.php";
  // $conexion = new Database(); //Creamos objeto de la clase para porder usar sus funciones
  // $conexion->connect();
?>

  <!-- Titulo con clase de bootstrap -->
  <h1 class="display-4" id="titulo"> Visualización de Datos</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <caption>
      <button class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevo" id="margen_inf"> Agregar Nuevo
        <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>
      </button>
    </caption>

    <!-- Table-hover sombrea celdas -->
    <!-- table-condensed para que se vea mas comprimido -->
    <!-- Parezca una celda la tabla -->
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed  table-bordered"> 

    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Nombre y Apellido</td>
      <td>Teléfono</td>
      <td>Correo</td>
      <td>Comuna</td>
      <td>Creado</td>
      <td>Actualizado</td>
      <td>Estado</td>
      <!-- Columnas extra para edición y eliminación -->
      <td>Editar</td>
      <td>Eliminar</td>
    </tr>


  <?php 


    $object_result = new Database();
    $object_result->connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `membresia`"; 
    $data = $object_result->query($query);

    foreach ($data as $ver ) {

  ?>
    <!-- Para ser llenado por PHP -->
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $ver[0] ?></td> <!-- Columna 1 es la 0 -->
      <td><?php echo $ver[1] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[2] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[3] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[4] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[5] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[6] ?></td>
      <td><?php 
      if ($ver[7] = 1) {
        <td><?php echo <i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i> ?></td>
      } else ($ver[7] = 0) {
        <td><?php echo <i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i> ?></td>
      } 
      ?></td>
      <!-- Editar y Eliminar -->
      <td>
       <button class="btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" ></button>
      </td> 
      <td>
       <button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
      }   // While
    ?>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si ven mas o menos lo que quiero? es en el $ver[7] que quiero hacer eso pero no se exactamente como , aprovechando esto me gustaria saber o si saben o otienen algun manual que me oriente a que cuando un checkbox este check (por si acaso lo hice con bootstrap 4 ese check) mande a la base de datos el valor de 1 y si no esta check lo ponga en 0 ya que tengo mi interfaz pero aun no se como hacer eso, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás igualando en vez de comparar, usas "=" en lugar de "==".
Además en un else no va condición a menos que sea un elseif
Y para terminar si pones un echo no importa que sea html, va encerrado en comillas.
deberías revisar la sintaxis de tu código.

```
<?php if ($ver[7] == 1) { 
    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  } else {
    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  }
```

o si quieres usar elseif

```
if ($ver[7] == 1) {
    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  } elseif($ver[7] == 0) {
    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>';
  }
```

Comment: Si amigo muchas gracias ya me di cuenta y lo puse asi: 

      <td><?php 
        if ($ver[7] == 1) { ?>
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <?php } else { ?>
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <?php } ?>


y ya funciona bien a la perfeccion lo que estoy viendo es enviar los datos  desde un modal de bootstrap a la base de datos y que traduzca el check o no check como 1 o 0 antes de enviar la data jejejeje

Comment: Por qué no lo envías por post mediante un formulario, luego en el action al que enviaste los datos obtienes el valor del check por su "name", y de ahí puedes enviarlo a la base de datos.
Un ejemplo
https://programarenphp.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/insertar-datos-del-formulario-a-tu-base-de-datos-en-php/

Comment: Si amigo hice algo asi :D gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un campo check no esta activo simplemente no envia nada es como si no existiera, entonce puedes hacer lo siguiente: `isset($_POST['campo_check'])?1:0`